# AWS serverless framework : How to get Cogntio user pool ID and App client ID in the Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a cognito user pool ID and the app client using Serverless.yml file

I am referring this link -

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/configure-cognito-user-pool-in-serverless.html

I want to use this Cognito user pool id in my lambda function code.

Is there any way I can get this User Pool ID and app client ID in my lambda code?

Is there any way serverless can create some environment variables, etc.  which can hold the values for user pool ID and the App client ID?

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

```yaml
myFunction:
  handler: '...'
  environment:
    USER_POOL_ID: # The name of the env var in your lambda
      Ref: CognitoUserPool # The name of your resource in Resources section
    APP_CLIENT_ID:
      Ref: CognitoUserPoolClient
```

It works because serverless uses CloudFormation under the hood.

See also [Return Values of AWS::Cognito::UserPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#aws-resource-cognito-userpool-return-values) and [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html).

Comment: Important to note that this will not work if you have resources that your userpool depends on, as you will force the userpool to be created first. An example is triggers. Triggers are created first, then the userpool. However, if you do this, it will create the pool first, causing a circular dependency.